# How to get IOTA testnet tokens and who distributes them in the first place?

Tags: testnet

I did try https://faucet.testnet.iota.org — its not working currently

Also will all old testnet tokens be compatible with the new devnet's?

Is the testnet still the same since the beginning of IOTA? Did it have a seed transition phase as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old testnet was changed into the (new) devnet. All the other (new) testnets started from scratch and do not share any tokens. I can confirm that testnet tokens I got from the faucet in November 2017 are still valid on devnet today. I don't know if there has been a CURL transition phase on devnet since I have not been involved that deeply at that time.

Usually the best way to get Devnet tokens when the faucet is down (which unfortuneately happens way too often...) is to come to [discord](https://discord.gg/rx5uu8z) and ask in the #testnet channel. There are a few helpful guys (e.g. Henry Wortel) who still have some devnet tokens (from the time where the faucet issued 10Mi each) and can share with you.

In this case I see you have already asked there (at least about the faucet which is down again).

Comment: is the source code available for this testnet faucet?

Comment: @instantlik I doubt it. The javascript client-side code is not minified/obfuscated, so it is quite readable, but the server-side code that checks the recaptcha and signs the transaction is not available.